# Does there exist $A$ of infinite order in $\{ A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}) : A^T = A^{-1} \}$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, infinite-groups

> Does there or does there not exist $A$ of infinite order in $\{ A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}) : A^T = A^{-1} \}$?

I know that elements of the form
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)\\\pm\sin(\theta) & \pm\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$$
are in this group, but do not know how to calculate their order.

Comment: What kind of orthogonal matrices do you know of?

Comment: I was thinking long something based on $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$, but it doesn't seem to work out.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}cos \theta & sin \theta \\ +- sin \theta & +- cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$ can be found by solving the $AA^T=I$ system. But then this matrix is of order 2?

Answer (score 6):

If we let
$$
A_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin\theta\\\sin\theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}
$$
be a rotation matrix representing a rotation of the plane by $\theta$, then we have $A_\theta A_\theta^T = A_\theta^TA_\theta = I$, which can be shown by carrying out the multiplications, or by noting that $A^T_\theta = A_{-\theta}$ is the opposite rotation of $A_\theta$. Now if we let $\theta$ be an irrational multiple of $\pi$ (like $1, \pi^2, e\pi, \sqrt 2, \ln 3$, there are many) then no positive power of $A_\theta$ will bring the plane back to where it started, so the order of $A_\theta$ is infinite.

Comment: Why does $A_\theta A^T_\theta = I$ hold for all angles, e.g. irrational?

Comment: @mavavilj The straight-forward answer is because
$$
A_\theta A^T_\theta = A_\theta A_\theta^T= \begin{pmatrix}\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta & \cos\theta\sin\theta - \cos \theta \sin\theta\\\cos\theta\sin\theta - \cos\theta\sin\theta & \cos^2\theta + \sin^2 \theta\end{pmatrix} = I
$$The more intuitive solution is to note that $A^T_\theta = A_{-\theta}$, so $A_\theta v$ is the vector $v$ rotated by $\theta$, and then $A^T_\theta (A_\theta v)$ is the vector $A_\theta v$ rotated back by $\theta$ again, so $A^T_\theta A_\theta v = v$ for any vector $v$. Only $I$ has this property.